Google Gemini API with wordpress error: "User location is not supported for the API use."
In WordPress I used PHP to connect to the Gemini API.
My code :
$api_url = 'https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent?key=' . $api_key ;
$body_ewr = '{"contents": [{"parts": [{"text": "Write a story"}]}]}';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_ewr);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: */*',
    'Host: generativelanguage.googleapis.com',
    'Connection: keep-alive'
]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
echo json_encode(array('message' => $decodedResponse));

Result :

{"error":{"code":400,"message":"User location is not supported for the
API use.","status":"FAILED_PRECONDITION"}}

But I used Java, JS, NodeJS, and they work！For now it only doesn't work in WordPress when I use PHP to connect the API .
Even when I created a new project in my Phpstorm, just a simple project, then ran it it works. They are same code. So, what's happened？

Is your Wordpress installation on a different machine? For example is it maybe on a hosted server? If so, that server might be in a location or country which is not allowed to use Gemini. That seems like the most likely reason for your problem.

Thank  you very much !!!!!IYeap ,I'm Chinese ,the server in  France！

According to this, neither France nor China are supported locations: https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/available-regions . Maybe from your machine in China you are using a VPN to connect to the internet? This might cause Gemini to believe your location is different. Of course the server will not use a VPN.

Yes，I using a VPN to  the internet！but why is only in wordpress？The java、JS、localPHP project is works！they are also in China？thats why i was so confused！！！

they are also in China...if they are all running on your personal machine in China in that case they will use the VPN and so it's ok: Gemini will see the public IP of the VPN and think they are located somewhere else. But if the Wordpress server is in France, it will not use VPN

Please edit your question to include all the required details. Leaving out important items such as VPN and the countries makes a difference in obtaining a good answer.
